# Using PowerShell to Check for Newly Created Local Admins

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, administration

So, as the title says: I am trying to write up a PowerShell script that checks to see if any user accounts have been added to the Local Administrators group or have been added as an Administrator on the local machine. I have been using Get-EventLog and Get-WinEvent in an attempt to accomplish what I a trying to do. The problem I am having is isolating or extracting the information I want out of the event logs.

This is what I have so far:

```
$Date = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-1)).Date

$Events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{
     StartTime = $Date
     LogName = 'Security'
     ProviderName = 'Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'
     ID = 4732
    }
```

I figure, if I can get the Username of the account that was added; which group or permissions it was given; and the date it was created, I can selectively output that information for each log over the last 24 hours. I'm not sure if I should be trying to use Get-Item or Get-Content, or if there is another way I should be trying to tackle this.

Comment: it looks like all you need is the membership of the local admin group. have you tried just using the default cmdlets for that?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have powershell v6.0+ installed, you'll need to use `-FilterXPath` instead:

```
$Alerts = Get-WinEvent -LogName Security -FilterXPath @'
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">*[System[
        EventID=4732 and 
        TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 604800000]]] and 
        *[EventData[Data[@Name="TargetDomainName"]='BUILTIN']] and 
        *[EventData[Data[@Name='TargetUserName']='Administrators']]
    </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
'@
```

You can use `-FilterHashTable` if you are running powershell v6.0 or higher. I would use something like this to check for those events. My servers don't all have v6, so I would have to run it remotely like so:

```
#Requires -Version 6.0
$alerts = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $computername -FilterHashtable @{
    StartTime = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-1)).Date
    LogName = 'Security'
    ProviderName = 'Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'
    ID = 4732
    TargetDomainName='Builtin'       ## These fields require
    TargetUserName='Administrators'  ## Powershell v6.0+
}
```

I'll include how I convert event log's local SIDs to usernames for reports, since it's a pain

```
# Process event(s)
if ($alerts) { foreach ($event in $alerts) {
    # Try and convert SID to account name:
    $sid = $event.Properties[1].Value.Value
    $localuser = ([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]::new($sid)
        ).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])).Value
    }
    # Use SID in case of failure
    if (!$localuser){$localuser=$event.Properties[1].Value}

    # Example action
    Write-Warning "User $localuser added to local Administrators group on $computername by user $($event.Properties[7].Value)\$($event.Properties[6].Value)"
}}

# Outputs
WARNING: User Server01\local-user01 added to local Administrators group on Server01 by user DOMAIN\AdminUser01
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, this is pretty much perfect except for this part:

`$localuser = Invoke-Command -computername $event.MachineName -ScriptBlock { 
        (([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]::new($Using:sid)
        ).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])).Value
    }`

I am going to be executing this on the machine(s) locally through some software we created at my company. I am not familiar with Invoke-Command and ($Using:sid). Is there a way to achieve the same result locally?

Comment: @davethoughts I've edited my answer to work - you can pretty much just remove those pieces.

Comment: I *strongly* recommend using a real windows event collection tool if you plan to run this every day though. e.g. WEF - it's built into windows, and you can feed it the exact same XPath data.